# htaccess: redirect all requests to different domain (without query arguments)

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect all requests (irrespective of what page is being requested) on sub.domain.com to newdomain.com? Currently I have

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

When a requests comes in for domain.com/shop/product the redirect goes to newdomain.com/shop/product while it should just go to newdomain.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use Rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This takes every request to `http://www.newdomain.com` but does not forward them.

Comment: Why do you think that? The docs state it quite clearly: "Use of the [R] flag causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser. If a fully-qualified URL is specified (that is, including `http://servername/`) then a redirect will be issued to that location. Otherwise, the current protocol, servername, and port number will be used to generate the URL sent with the redirect." http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: First of all I tested it and didn't work, then I went on to find out the cause of it because as you said this is a valid rule, but having `/$1` at the end worked on most of my servers (I haven't tested in all).

Comment: Adding `/$1` will add the path of the request to the new domain. That is not what the OP intendet. For seeing what is going on, you can increase the `RewriteLogLevel`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Answer (score 9):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will forward any GET requests.