# Laravel site redirect to another laravel domain in ubuntu server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I have two domains, the first one is payment.propnex.net and the second one is digi.propnex.net.
I want the first domain to redirect me to the second domain immediately after visiting the url. How could I achieve that?

Server `var/www/html`
[image]

.htaccess from first domain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes

    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://digi.propnex.net/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]        

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT. I created new `.htaccess` file in root directory of first domain and added

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://payment.propnex.net [NC,OR]  
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://digi.propnex.net [NC]  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://digi.propnex.net/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Still when not redirecting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess: redirect all requests to different domain (without query arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255967/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-different-domain-without-query-arguments)

Comment: The easiest way it put a meta tag on `payment.propnex.net`page that user access

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=digi.propnex.net" />

Comment: what do you mean by that @TruongDang

Comment: @Don'tPanic i already did that i write new `.htaccess` file in root directory of first domain and still nothing

Comment: Really? Your question does not mention that?  Can you show us? `still nothing` - what does that mean? What happens? What does devtools show?  Apache logs?

Comment: when i visit `payment.propnex.net` it still not redirect to `digi.propnex.net`