# Redirect Everything After the Domain With .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

How would I redirect, for example `domain.com/index.php?677775=1` to `domain.net`, with the same uri after the domain?

Don't know how to explain it, but I did my best.

EXAMPLE: when you go to `http://fb.com/***`, it redirects you to `http://www.facebook.com/***`.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar post : [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

It's not really complicated, you just have to write this in the htaccess file of the domain to redirect :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.facebook.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I hope I could help you.