# 301 redirect with .htaccess from old domain to a new

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are domains old.test.ru and test.ru. How do I redirect all pages from old.test.ru/* to test.ru/*?

I have these .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   # redirect from index.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm), main.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm), home.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)main\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)home\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]

   # redirect from dev and www
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.test\.ru$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.ru$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test\.ru/$1 [R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I think that last line

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test\.ru/$1 [R=301,NC]`

should work, but it doesn't.

It works for:

```
old.test.ru/about.php -> test.ru/about.php
old.test.ru/company.php -> test.ru/company.php
old.test.ru/contact.php -> test.ru/contact.php
```

But didn't work for:

```
old.test.ru/some/about.php -> test.ru/some/about.php
old.test.ru/some1/company.php -> test.ru/some1/company.php
old.test.ru/some2/contact.php -> test.ru/some2/contact.php
old.test.ru/some2/subsome/contact.php -> test.ru/some2/subsome/contact.php
```

What should I change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your last rule with this:

```
 # redirect from dev and www
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|old)\.test\.ru$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://test.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Update:** To remove `index.php` etc from URL:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|old)\.test\.ru$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)((?:index|default)\.(?:php|html?))?$ http://test.ru/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work ... Now even redirect with old.test.ru to test.ru stopped working ...

Comment: Make sure to put this code before any other rule you have. Also tell me what is your Apache version?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (FreeBSD)

Server built:   Nov 10 2012 20:55:13

Comment: ok, place this code just below `RewriteBase` line and test in a different browser.

Comment: .htaccess:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)main\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)home\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]

 # redirect from dev and www
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.test\.ru$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.ru$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test\.ru/$1 [R=301,NC]
</IfModule>`

Comment: You still have other rules above my suggested rule. Place my rule just below `RewriteBase` line also tell me what is your URL that used to test this?

Comment: If your URL starts with `dev.` then your `RewriteCond` should have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|dev)\.dslaboratories\.ru$ [NC]` Also is there any .htaccess anywhere inside `spectralDNC`?

Comment: Of course its `^(www|dev)\.ds...`. Yes there is another .htaccess in `/spectralDNC/`:
`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /spectralDNC/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Ah that .htaccess is the reason of this problem. If you notice `http://dev.dslaboratories.ru/foo` just redirects fine :)

Comment: If you have `.htaccess` in `spectralDNC` then you 2 options, either place above code in `spectralDNC/.htaccess` before all other code OR else move that simple rule to `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: Ok, Keep in mind if any subfolder has .htaccess then it takes over.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) on `old.test.ru` rather than using `mod_rewrite` if you want to redirect all requests.

In the configuration for `old.test.ru` use:

```
Redirect permanent / http://test.ru/
```

Comment: It doesn't work too - there is an error: On this page, discovered cyclic forwarding.

Comment: You will have to clean out your `RewriteRule` that do the rewrite from `old.test.ru` to `test.ru` in your `.htaccess` file. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.test\.ru$ [OR]`.

Comment: don't understand what its mean?

Comment: I assume you have a `<VirtualHost>` or similar in the `httpd.conf` for `old.test.ru` it's in this configuration you put the redirect. Also you do not need to do the redirect in `.htaccess` since it's already taken care off. Look in the link I provided and it's explained in there. Is `old.test.ru` only an `Alias` for `test.ru`?