# php routing old php site to new ror site

Tags: php, url-routing

i have a site abc.com in php and now made anothers site abcd.com on rails, i wish to redirect all requests that go to the php site to redirect to abcd.com...
example:
abc.com/page3 -> abcd.com/page3
abc.com/non_existing_link ->abcd.com

this php site is just hard coded, not using any framework and i wish to write script in index.php which would accept ny link towards abc.com and  then check the extension and redirect it accordingly to the corresponding links on abcd.com... i was suggested to write a controller from a collegue and i am not familiar with mvc functionalities nor th controllers class and stuff...

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver runs apache, I would recommend placing a .htaccess-file in the root of your original server as in the following answer: [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain). If you would like to keep the names the same (redirect to exactly the same name on your new domain), use the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

This method works with very limited amount of work/coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you there are several ways to achieve so:

1. Using php redirect in all php pages.

[How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

2. Modifying .htaccess file in your directory

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

3. If you have a cpanel of other controler system from hosting provider then do it directly there.

Comment: i dont wish to prepend a redirection code on each page of the site... i have around 40-100 individual php pages and i wish to  just check the url etension and get its corresponding value from the xml file json file with oldlink => new link records base i have and redirect.. just wanna route using single script with cases

Comment: i used the 301 redirect technique in htaccess file... now when i open abc.com/team.php it redirects to abcd.com/abc.com/team.php , but all i want to do is check whats the subdirectory in the url after abc.com and get its corresponding redirection from the xml records i have and redict the page to that url....