# Redirect old subdomain to new domain

Tags: .htaccess

I recently changed my website and copied all contents from old domain to new domain. The old domain I had was a subdomain on a free webhost and Now I want to redirect all pages this to new.

**My goal**

http://old.domain.com/anything ==> http://newdomain.com

---

How can I do it in htaccess? I have already tried with redirect but just the homepage is redirect.  Help is appriciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 # This will redirect a subdomain to another domain
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```