# Using .htaccess to redirect URL to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm hosting a forum and have recently decided to move it to a sub-domain instead.

As such, I moved all the forum files in to `var/www/forum` and I can access the forums just fine through this directory, i.e `example.net/forum`.

I've also set up the sub-domain in my apache virtual host so that if I go to `forum.example.net` it will display the forums to me and this also works fine.

All I need to do now is set up a .htaccess to redirect people using the directory URL `example.net/forum` to `forum.example.net`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain) gets me close, but not quite there as it will continually redirect me.

Ideally I'd like to carry their request over too, e.g `example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?example` gets redirected to `forum.example.net/viewtopic.php?example`.

Throughout my search for the answer, mod-rewrite may work but I am not too sure how to implement it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/forum/.htaccess` you can use this rule as **your first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forum.%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It is the only rule in my `.htaccess` file, which is in `/var/www/forum/`. I've done a hard-refresh but if I go to example.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=436 it doesn't redirect me.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^www.example.net$" [OR]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^example.net$"
RewriteRule ^/?forum/(.*)$ http://forum.example.net/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: this did not work for me. I.e nothing has changed since I added it. I am correct in assuming that the .htaccess file I add this to is the one in the forum directory?