# 301 Redirects - Not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am looking to 301 redirect (in .htaccess) around 15 WP blog URLs on an old domain to the new, corresponding URLs on a new domain.

Along with enabling the the Apache mod_rewrite module and ReWriteEngine, my .htaccess file contains a combination of the following:

```
Redirect 301 /old1 http://www.example.com/new1
Redirect 301 /old2 http://www.example.com/new2
Redirect 301 /old3 http://www.example.com/new3
Redirect 301 /old4 http://www.example.com/new4
Redirect 301 /old5 http://www.example.com/new5
Redirect 301 /old6 http://www.example.com/new6
Redirect 301 /old7 http://www.example.com/new7
```

The problem is, instead of /old1 redirecting to http://www.example.com/new1, it's instead redirecting to **http://www.example.comnew1**, which of course is invalid.

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: "I am having a difficult time doing this in the .htaccess file" and "my .htaccess file contains a combination of the following" is not entirely clear. Does your .htaccess file contain these 3 lines exactly or something else (too)? What happens now?

Comment: Hi, I saw you updated the description of your original problem after I commented, but you didn't reply back to me, so I'm not sure if you're still looking for a solution to your problem. If you do: which other commands does your .htaccess file contain (especially before those redirects), or is that all? Thanks.