# Redirect all pages at one time

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, blogger

I would like to know how to redirect all URLs blogger for Wordpress:

```
http://www.atrack.meusite.com/12015/05/myfirstpost.html
```

For:

```
http://www.atrack.meusite.com/myfirstpost/
```

pages:

```
http://www.atrack.meusite.com/p/contact.html
```

For:

```
http://www.atrack.meusite.com/contact/
```

Category:

```
http://www.atrack.meusite.com/search/label/print
```

For:

```
http://www.atrack.meusite.com/category/print/
```

Perform all changes without the need for redirection by redirect?

Comment: Did you try anything? This shouldn't be to hard with .htaccess redirects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite / RewriteRule for apache.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Perhaps add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule .*/(.*).html /$1
RewriteRule search/label/(.*) /category/$1
```