# Htaccess Redirect Issue for sub directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website functionaloncology.com 
I want to redirect functionaloncology.com domain to cancertreatmentmx.com

But the sub pages and directories redirect on same domain e.g
http://functionaloncology.com/amygdalin-b17/
this will redirect on same domain

But only this url functionaloncology.com redirect to cancertreatmentmx.com

Can anyone please help me to write the .htaccess code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess of `functionaloncology.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?functionaloncology\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://cancertreatmentmx.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: when i try to open http://functionaloncology.com/amygdalin-b17/  
then it redirect to this
http://cancertreatmentmx.com/404.shtml

Comment: Yes i want to redirect only home page not other pages. that is what i have asked. i have used the code above but it not working , my website is build in Joomla CMS.

Comment: Yes but the above page is also redirect to the redirected website and causing the 404 error on redirected website. i want to this link http://functionaloncology.com/amygdalin-b17/ remain same but only home page http://functionaloncology.com/ redirect to this http://cancertreatmentmx.com.

Comment: My original rule (rolled back now) will **only redirect home page** not other pages. You must clear your browser cookies and also provide your current htaccess in question