# .htaccess redirect from old root domain to new specific sub-dir domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NEWfoobar.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have this line of code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578810, inside `.htaccess` and it currently works by migrating `www.OLDfoobar.com` to `www.NEWfoobar.com` and all its sub-directory structure just fine (intended behavior, all good)

now, how do I add additional rule that captures `www.OLDfoobar.com` to redirect to one specific page in `www.NEWfoobar.com`? *say for example `www.NEWfoobar.com/welcomeToNewDomain*

The `[L]` flag is what gets me. and btw, I'm not so sure about what the `$1` is for. That can't be a regex flag for the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, yes?

***ACCEPTED ANSWER***

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.NEWfoobar.com/some/sub/directory [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NEWfoobar.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what the current script is doing fine. besides this, I'd like to implement an additional rule where it redirects from simply **olddomain** to **newdomain/sub-directory-uri**

Comment: @starkeen, my prev comment and paragraph 2 is as clear as it gets. so yes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NEWfoobar.com/welcomeToNewDomain [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` meant use the first capture group which is the value between the brackets on the left.

The L in the options means stop processing the rewrite rules (ie this is the Last Rule) if the match applies.

The `^(.*)$` means:

```
`^` match beginning of string
`(.*)` match zero or more characters and store in capture group 1
`$` match end of string
```

If I've miss understood an you only want to redirect the root requests while keeping the old capture you need to add a new rule **before** the existing one that reads

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.NEWfoobar.com/welcomeToNewDomain [R=301,L]
```

This will match either an empty path or just `/`

Comment: ok, got it. but it still doesn't work. the `RewriteRule` *pattern* basically means any string. so if I input `www.OLDfoobar.com/any-sub-directory-string`... given your suggested target, I'd be redirected to `http://www.NEWfoobar.com/welcomeToNewDomain/any-sub-directory-string`

Comment: @Valkyrurr No you wouldn't because I have not included the `$1` in the target rule so it would not include it. Also the key element is that the rule pattern will match any path in it's entirety.  If this rule isn't working, what is the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: @Valkyrurr I may have miss understood the question slightly, see my updated answer.  If you wanted `www.OLDfoobar.com/any-sub-directory-string` to redirect to a single url, use my first answer.  If you want simply to add a new rewrite rule that is just `www.OLDfootbar.com` then insert my second example before your existing rewriterule

Comment: Your updated answer is what I am looking for. Thank you. I misinterpret the use of `$1`, now everything is clear.