# htaccess: Missing first Trailing Slash in redirect Url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have create a new website for my company and we decide to keep the old one and make it redirects all content  and pages  to similar content pages to the new website.

I have create an htaccess file to replace the old file at the old website.

This htaccess file contains the following lines:

    `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com
    Redirect 301 /contact http://newsite.com/contact/
    Redirect 301 /category/products http://newsite.com/shop/
    Redirect 301 /category/tools/makita http://newsite.com/shop/makita/
    Redirect 301 /products/new-products http://newsite.com/shop/whats-new/
    ....etc...
    </IfModule>`

Now the problem is that (except the home page that worksfine) all other pages redirects but **missing the first trailing slash after the domain name**.
For example:
`oldsite.com/category/tools/makita  ===> newsite.comcategory/tools/makita`

What can i do to resolve this? I forgot to mention that both websites are in Wordpress CMS on Apache Server (php 5.6 and FastCgi Module)

Thanks in Advance!

P.S.: English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: Thanks for your quote but its not duplicate! My own problem is that missing the first trailing slash of the permalink (after the domain name)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the late response, but I think you want to add a trailing slash to the first url

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), So I'm flagging this post for deletion.