# .htaccess point a folder on subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to point a folder to my subdomain after click on link. When i click on

```
<a href="http://fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl">
                <div id="mmpfotobudkalogo" class="col-lg-4">
                    <h2><img src="/img/fb/logo_fotobudka.png" width="188px"></h2>
                    <p class="text-standard">Klasyczna fotobudka w nowoczesnym stylu</p>
                </div>
                </a>
```

The browser links me to: "http://fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl/fotobudka" and 500 error, I need to point a folder to this link cause defaultly creater by server is not working

Folder created by adding a subdomain: mmpstu/public/fotobudka

I need to point this folder to link that browser brings me on.

Comment: I don't find your question entirely clear. On which of your two sites is the link located? What is the href of the link? And where do you expect to land after clicking?

Comment: I have img logo on website, on that img is link to 
<a href="http://fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl">
On my domain i created a subdomain and i want to after click to go there>
My .htaccess file is located in /mmpstudio/public/ and my fotobudka folder is located /mmpstudio/public/fotobudka which was defaultly created by server after creating an subdomain

Comment: Your image link needs to have `http://` at the beginning of it, otherwise it will try to link to the `/fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl` path within your site root.

Comment: Can u change this and answer ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: Nope, i don't want to change old domain to new, i want to after click on <a> on "domain.com" to send me to "subdomain.domain.com".
After click on <a href="http://fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl"> browser send me to: http://fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl/fotobudka, it's ok but files in mmpstudio/public/fotobudka are not working i just want to redirect browser to this folder

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML looks oddly structured to me. Not *wrong*, but I would put as little inside the `<a>` tag as you can get away with, to make it easier to see what's going on.

Second, [you don't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) Try doing this with `mod_redirect` and you may find it easier to understand.

```
Redirect / http://mmpstudio.pl/fotobudka/
```

Comment: The link `<a href="fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl">` needs to be `<a href="http://fotobudka.mmpstudio.pl">`.