# redirectmatch to external url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, external

Im new here at stack overflow, and don't have a lot of coding experience, and was thinking that my chances of finding a coding genius to help me, must be biggest in here.

So here it goes:

I have this url: https://www.domain1/numbers/variables

And i want to redirect that to https://www.domain2/pages/hello

I want to redirect everything that is: www.domain1/numbers/
...no matter which variables that comes along with it.

And the page i want to redirect to, is always the same.

I hope somebody can help, thanks.

Best regards
Nicolai

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ (www\.)?domain1.com/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.com/pages/hello [R=301,L]
```

The condition grabs both `https://domain1.com/anything` and `https://www.domain1.com/anything` and redirects them to `https://www.domain2.com/pages/hello` by using `R=301` which is a permanent redirection. While testing you might want to change that to `R=302` which is a temporary redirect.

You can see this rule working here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=6c02aa2d-ff08-5d45-b07e-2cad294a329f

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

***EDIT***

See code below based on your specific specifications based in comment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ (www\.)?skip.com/$1 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://kapsio.com/pages/velkommen-til-kapsio [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.

I need to redirect this: https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/variables

to: https://www.kapsio.com/pages/velkommen-til-kapsio

So only skip.dk/fmemilverification and no other skip.dk/pages or skip.dk/blogpost

Is this correct?

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ (www\.)?skip.com/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kapsio.com/pages/velkommen-til-kapsio [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Almost. See my edit in my answer, you had a small mistake which I've corrected. You were missing `https://` in the RewriteRule. That needs to be there in order for it to work, otherwise it won't switch domains.

Comment: Ok. so i added in what you put in the edit, and got a 500 internal server error

I change the .htacces file from this:

# BEGIN WordPress      
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>        
RewriteEngine On      
RewriteBase /      
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d       
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]      
</IfModule>      

# END WordPress

Comment: To this:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>      
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ (www\.)?skip.com/$1 [NC]        
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://kapsio.com/pages/velkommen-til-kapsio [R=301,L]      
</IfModule>    


Why did i get a 500 internal server error?

Comment: Don't remove the first bit. I never said to do that, if it is a WordPress website then you need to leave the original bit in there.

Comment: My bad. now i done this and still get error 500
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ (www\.)?skip.com/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://kapsio.com/pages/velkommen-til-kapsio [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress