# htaccess redirect with old domain to new under same hosting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have an old domain named mev-hongkong.com pointed to the same hosting of my new domain mothersenvogue.com.hk.

I am trying to apply a redirect of this page http://mev-hongkong.com/become-an-mev-member/ to its new url path which is https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/membership-privileges/

What rewrite rule should I apply for me to be able to pass the old url to its new domain counterpart?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: @cabrerahector how I understand the link provided, it only shows how to redirect all pages under the old domain to the new domain but how would I declare a redirect rule from one specific page to the other under 2 separate domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple .htaccess rule should work

Permanent redirect from old-page to new-page

```
Redirect 301 /become-an-mev-member/ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/membership-privileges/
```

as reference

https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Comment: Thank you @DaFois! It worked!

However, what if I have 2 different URLs to serve? Like this:
mev-hongkong.com/product-category/babies-tots/
mev-hongkong.com/product-category/babies-tots/?add_to_wishlist=10221

should land to

https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/babies-tots/ ?

What rewrite rule and regex can be used?

Thanks!

Comment: on a new line do the same for every link you want to redirect.

Comment: is there a regex I can use for it? I have thousands of products needed to apply redirect to.