# how to connect domain from wildcard subdomain

Tags: server, subdomain, cpanel, wildcard

i **have 2 domain**.

my first domain example is **justfortest.com** and *i was create Wildcard sub domain*.
any sub domain now available on justfortest.com.

and my second domain example is **myhope.com**.

Now *i want **myhope.com** access **some wildcard domain from justfortest.com***. may be like *hope.justfortest.com*.

> i have been point A record from myhope.com to IP server
>   justfortest.com. but nothing happen.

What's should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can redirect this into any subdomain using .htaccess rewrite rule at domain host

Comment: yes, I've done. but i want poin myhope.com from hope.justfortest.com

Comment: in htaccess file you can give that type of domain name. domain vendor sites also give that kind of redirection facility

Comment: can u give me an example please ?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hope.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain

Comment: Sorry i don't need to redirect page. i need to load same folder wildcard subdomain on cpanel.

Comment: i just addon domain and create some folder to link to wildcard domain... I really say thx u for your effort to help. ^^