# Redirect All Old Domain Paths to NewDomain Paths

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dns

I have Shifted my website to NewDomain and Dumped my Database and Files to New Domain, Everthing is Fine .

But i want to redirect My Old Domain to New Domain,
Like :

https://OldDomain.com to https://NewDomain.com ,
and also

https://OldDomain.com/image/abcd to https://NewDomain.com/image/abcd

i want to every path of my Old Domain to Redirect to New Domain path.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578810/2232127
Disregard the accepted answer, it's for redirecting only to the index page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Answer (score 0):

I tried as JensV Suggested, But It didnt worked in My Case, those are redirecting to My index url, but not the specific path