# Redirect from blog.domain.org to domain.com using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to know the correct htaccess code redirect from blog.domain.**org** to domain.**com**

I have this code below

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.domain.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA] < domain.com

Not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)