# Rewrite all to 1 domain except Joomla administrator

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla

I have a website that has 10 domain pointers they all point to the master-domain. I use this code in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !masterdomain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://masterdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] [R,L]
```

It works but I want https://masterdomain.com/administrator to point to https://licencepointerdomain.com/administrator/*

I tried :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ! masterdomain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://masterdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] [R,L]
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“can someone help me on this issue?”_, is not a good way to ask here. You should explain what you already tried, what you came up with during your own research, etc.

Comment: @MessageDJ if you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is this it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1945568/2943403