# Redirect Url with everything after tld

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So is this possible to redirect URL with all the parameters and file names too to another URL. For example, there is a URL like

> example.com/anyfile.php?param1=data2

So is this possible to redirect this URL to

> example2.com/anyfile.php?param1=data2

Without having the file **anyfile.php** Maybe something to do with .htaccess or anything?

Comment: Yes. It is possible with `.htaccess`. Please refer the following link https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: Yeah, i see there, But it only allows to redirect to index.php or any other file without params and file name.

Comment: You will need to add regular expressions in the syntax. Please check the document thoroughly. I am using my mobile so I may not be accurate. 
You are looking for the Query String Append flag -e.g

`RewriteRule ^anyfile.php(.*)$ http://example2.com/anyfile.php?q=$1 [QSA]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)