# Rewrite Specific ULR

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i must create a Apache rewrite that redirect only a specif url vs a new domain.

this url:
https://oldodomain.com/url
new url:
https://newdomain.com/url

but i must exclude all non perfect matching for example

https://oldodomain.com/url.html or https://oldodomain.com/url/doc.css or https://oldodomain.com/url/er/

how i cam resolve ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. What are "non perfect matchings"?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite must be redirect only for https://oldodomain.com/url
but not for
https://oldodomain.com/url.html (with exentsion) or with any subfolder

https://oldodomain.com/url/doc/
https://oldodomain.com/url/doc.css